# How to model roles hierarchies (and relations between them) with Grakn / Graql?

Tags: model, hierarchy, roles, vaticle-typedb, vaticle-typeql

I'm starting to use Grakn and I'm having a hard time with how roles and relationships are "linked". Specifically, I am having some difficulty modeling role hierarchies.

Considering a fictional example with two scenarios, first suppose I have only two types: person and object; and a purchasing relationship between a customer role hierarchy and a product role hierarchy.

So, I would have something like:

type: person

- role: customer level 1
- role: customer level 2 (sub customer level 1)
- role: customer level 3 (sub customer level 2)

  ...

type: object

- role: product level 1
- role: product level 2 (sub product level 1)
- role: product level 3 (sub product level 2)
  ...

The relationship is unique (buys) and is used to relate roles considering the respective levels in the hierarchy:

```
     customer level 1 --- buys --- product level 1
     customer level 2 --- buys --- product level 2
     customer level 3 --- buys --- product level 3
```

In a second scenario, I would have only one role hierarchy, the customer one and the object type would have only one role: product. So, the relationships would be something like:

```
     customer level 1 --- buys --- product
     customer level 2 --- buys --- product
     customer level 3 --- buys --- product
```

How can I model this kind of problem with Grakn (Graql)? I would appreciate it if someone could show how this (or similar) problem would be modeled with Graql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To construct a role hierarchy in Graql you need to override a parent role with a child by defining a child relation.

I think that for your first case there are two possible options, depending upon what you want to restrict:

```
define

buys sub relation,
  abstract,
  relates product,
  relates customer;

buys-level-1 sub buys,
  relates product-level-1 as product,
  relates customer-level-1 as customer;

buys-level-2 sub buys-level-1,
  relates product-level-2 as product-level-1,
  relates customer-level-2 as customer-level-1;

buys-level-3 sub buys-level-2,
  relates product-level-3 as product-level-2,
  relates customer-level-3 as customer-level-2;

person sub entity,
  plays customer-level-1,
  plays customer-level-2,
  plays customer-level-3;

object sub entity,
  plays product-level-1,
  plays product-level-2,
  plays product-level-3;
```

In this scenario, if you inserted a `buys-level-3` relation:

```
insert 
$per isa person; $obj isa object;
$b(product-level-3: $obj, customer-level-3: $per) isa buys-level-3;
```

You will be able to match for it using `buys-level-2`, `buys-level-1` and `buys`. So this query will get back the person and the relation we just inserted:

```
match $b(customer-level-1: $per) isa buys-level-1; get;
```

Alternatively, you can change the restriction like this:

```
buys-level-3 sub buys,
  relates product-level-3 as product,
  relates customer-level-3 as customer;
```

In this case the `match` we made would not return the inserted relation or person. Let the restrictions that you want to impose on your queries/data guide you here for the best model choice.

The second scenario is then easy to see, we have:

```
define

buys sub relation,
  abstract,
  relates product,
  relates customer;

buys-level-1 sub buys,
  relates product,
  relates customer-level-1 as customer;

buys-level-2 sub buys-level-1,
  relates product,
  relates customer-level-2 as customer-level-1;

buys-level-3 sub buys-level-2,
  relates product,
  relates customer-level-3 as customer-level-2;

person sub entity,
  plays customer-level-1,
  plays customer-level-2,
  plays customer-level-3;

object sub entity,
  plays product;
```

In any of these scenarios, you can retrieve all `buys` relations and their roleplayers with:

```
match $b(customer: $per, product: $obj) isa buys; get;
```